# StopForeground Doesn't Remove Foreground Service Notification on Galaxy S21 Ultra

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, service, notifications

I have a simple foreground service that runs a timer and shows an ongoing notification with a progress bar. However, the following code on the service does not cause the notification to be removed when the app runs on my Galaxy S21 Ultra. It works perfectly fine on the emulator running the same version of Android (version 11) and my S6 running Android 7.

```
StopForeground(StopForegroundFlags.Remove);
```

I've tried so many ways to get this working I couldn't possibly list them all here. I don't want to stop the service (which doesn't remove the notification anyway despite people saying it does; I tried it).

It's almost like it thinks I'm calling

```
StopForeground(StopForegroundFlags.Detach);
```

even though I'm not - and I why would it work that way on this specific device (and run correctly in an emulator running the same version of Android)?

I'm flummoxed.

**Edit:** I should mention that in all cases, the notification disappears after the app is closed. I call *StopForeground(StopForegroundFlags.Remove)* in the *OnTaskRemoved* event in the service class before stopping the service. When I comment StopForegound out, the notification still disappears when the app is closed on the S21. Which means that a) my call to StopForeground is redundant and b) stopping the service in this way does behave as expected.

I need to experiment more. There's another way I can stop the service when I want to remove the notification, which is to tell the service to stop itself (instead of relying on OnTaskRemoved to do it).

I really don't want to have to start and stop the service every time the timer needs to run though, especially as the user can do this repeatedly at will. And it still wouldn't explain why it's only a problem on the S21 and not on the S6 or the emulator, making it a shoddy workaround.

**Edit 2:** I've now tried stopping the service when the user taps stop (by calling StopSelf on the service), *instead* of calling StopForeground. The same problem seems to happen. The notification persists on the S21, but it's even worse as restarting the service when play is tapped doesn't replace the notification. But again, it works as expected on the emulator (I haven't tried the S6 this time). This is bizarre.

Comment: *"I don't want to stop the service (which doesn't remove the notification anyway despite people saying it does; I tried it)."* - That .. doesn't seem possible. If the service isn't there anymore, I don't see how the notification could continue. I mention this, even though it isn't what you want to do, because it might be worth looking into. Before attempting StopForeground. Could there possibly have been TWO services started, and you are only altering one?

Comment: Thanks. Indeed it is strange. I start the service in MainActivity.cs, in OnCreate using StartService(new Intent(this, typeof(TimerService))) so it shouldn't start two services. Definitely something to check though (I'll make the service write a unique identifier of some sort to the output). Of course, if this is what's happening, why is it not a problem in the S6 or the emulator?

Comment: I've just done that test - it does only start one service.

Comment: Very strange. Two hypotheses: 1) There is something different at the Android level on that device. But in that case, I would expect to see posts by non-Xamarin devs complaining about it. 2) Xamarin's implementation expects something, that is somehow missing on that device, and the implementation quietly swallows the failure. It sounds like the service is still running (detached), even after telling it to Stop - but not in a state where it can do anything useful. I would breakpoint just before stopping it, then let it stop, examine output. Compare to emu output.  Set maximum verbosity.

Comment: ... Bottom line is you've done all the right tests; submit a github issue, with as much info as you can. A "minimum reproducible project" definitely needed in this case. Ideally a simple `xamarin.android` project - don't need `xamarin.forms` for this.

Comment: WTH?! It works when I step through it after a break point. I'm starting to suspect it's some kind of thread timing issue which only crops up on the S21 due to the CPU management being different somehow (or just being a much faster CPU). I don't know.

Comment: As a hack, after StopForeground, invoke a trivial method on UI thread with 250 ms delay. Put a breakpoint inside that delayed method - and remove your earlier breakpoint(s). That should allow any UI clean-up to take place. It that works, then you'll have to do any continuation from that delayed UI method. Ugh, but if it works ...

Comment: I had the same thought this morning and 'ugh' was my reaction too! I've just discovered that if I don't cancel the other notifications when I stop the timer (the app creates specific event notifications in addition to the ongoing one) then the foreground service notification does disappear. This fixes the problem for me but I'm still left with no explanation as why this is the case on this one device. Edit: Actually, cancelling the other notifications _before_ calling StopForeground also works.

Comment: @RobotHead Is your service using android:exported="true"? I experienced the same but only in that case.